# Combing data of two rxjs observables using map

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, nestjs

I have two services that make calls to two separate external APIs (productDataService, productPrice) that return observables. I then have a third service called productService that needs to ultimately return an observable to my controller that is a result of calling functions from the two external services. As you will see below I am getting a list of products from one service (outer observable) and need to then in turn call another service function (inner observable) to get the price for that product.

```
// Both services functions are using HttpService and returning observables.
getProductInfo() {
    return this.productDataService.getProducts()
        .pipe(map((prod: any) => this.productPriceService.getProductPriceById(prod.id)
            .pipe(map(price => {
                (
                    {
                        id: prod.created,
                        name: prod.amount,
                        price
                    }
                )
            }))))
}
```

Here are the service functions for reference:

```
// getProducts (returns an observable of an array of type product)
        return this.httpService.get(url, config).pipe(map(res => res.data.list.map(item => {
            return {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name
            }
        })));

// getProductPriceById (returns an Observable of type number)
return this.httpService.get(url, config).pipe(map(res => res.data.price));
```

Comment: When going from your outer observable to your inner observable, you need to use switchMap or mergeMap instead of map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the **[`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)** operator instead of the `map` operator, in the outer `.pipe` call.

```
getProductInfo() {
  return this.productDataService.getProducts()
    .pipe(switchMap((prod: any) => this.productPriceService.getProductPriceById(prod.id)
      .pipe(map(price => {
        ({
          id: prod.created,
          name: prod.amount,
          price
        })
      }))))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this return an array or an Observable<any[]>? I would like this to follow the normal async flow of an Angular app going from service to component or like a NestJS app going from service to controller as an Observable that gets subscribed to.

Comment: Ideally you should be doing this in the `getProducts` method itself and your component shouldn't make that second API Call to get the product's price. Depends on quite a lot of use-cases.

If you want to only get the price of one product at a time and then append it in the data at a specific index, you could just call the `getProductPriceById` separately and then add it to the product present at a specific index in the products array.